# Finding the zeros of $f(x)=-0.006x^4+0.140x^3-0.053x^2+1.79x$

Tags: functions, polynomials

> How would you find zeros for the polynomial $f(x)=-0.006x^4+0.140x^3-0.053x^2+1.79x$ with a degree of $4$?

I know a zero is $x=0$, but how do I find the other ones, and are there any imaginary zeros? I am able to see an actual $x$-int on the graph, but how would I find that with this function? Thank you.

Comment: $−0.006x^4+0.140^3−0.053^2+1.79=-x(0.006^3-0.140^2+0.053-1.79)$ then $x=0$ and $6x^3-140x^2+53x-1790=0$  maybe you can use Newton's method.

Answer (score 1):

As  MathYobani commented, you are left with
$$6 x^3-140 x^2+53 x-1790=0$$ Use the method for [cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function). Not very pleasant because working with huge numbers but the key result is
$$\Delta=-21275507448$$ which means that there is one real root and two complex roots.

For the real root, you can use the hyperbolic solution and get the nasty
$$x=\frac{70}{9}+\frac{\sqrt{18646}}{9}  \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{853400 \sqrt2}{(9323)^{\frac 32}}\right)\right)\approx 23.4977$$